# install4j Updater -> Java Path not remembered

Tags: java, install4j

Our application is installed first time via install4j and after this installation we have the file inst_jre.cfg in the .install4j folder where the "selection" of the Java installation was selected during the installation. This is fine.

Now, when there is an update with "Update downloader with silent Version check", an update is recognised but again the install4j Assitant asks the user to give the Java installation path. It is not clear why the install4j assitant asks for the Java path again even though the Java path is stored in the inst_jre.cfg file. How can this be avoided?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 9, a new installer does not check previous installations for their preferred JRE.

One way to let the next installer know about a JRE is to set an an environment variable with a "Modify an environment variable on Windows" action and add the and environment variable entry on the "General settings->JRE Bundles->Search Sequence" step.

Comment: Hi @IngoKegel, we use install4j 8 version. I checked out the "JRE Search Sequence". Right now it is set as the Environment variable JAVA_HOME. The Application is installed 1st time by the IT Support and they select the Java for the installation and the inst_jre.cfg is created. Now when there is an update, would it be possible to read the used JRE from the inst_jre.cfg (i.e The value here as an Environment Variable) in the updater because the JRE that is used by the support could be dynamic.?

Comment: Unfortunately, as of install4j 9 this is not possible.